# Magento installation issue

Tags: magento

Am getting below error before installing magento could any one help me on this

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number: 67392566

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow. Here is the [list of topics we discuss here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) It looks like your question rather belongs to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score -1):

Go to var/report and open file with this number 67392566 and see the exact error then send me so I can help you exactly with your query.